# mosh-server needs a UTF-8 native locale to run

Tags: ssh, gentoo, mosh

I am trying to connect from my Gentoo to RHEL server. Both have `mosh` installed, however I get this error:

```
petanb@localhost ~/Documents $ mosh root@server 
mosh-server needs a UTF-8 native locale to run.

Unfortunately, the local environment ([no charset variables]) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII",

The client-supplied environment ([no charset variables]) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII".

LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
Connection to server closed.
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.
```

On RHEL I have following locales:

```
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: The problem seem to be on Gentoo side, connecting to debian server produces same error, connecting using other distros works.

UPDATE2: I fixed it by adding

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG
```

into `~/.bashrc`

Comment: For those using Ubuntu or any Debian like distro, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116779/349837) may be a solution.

Answer (score 5):

`mosh` uses the locale environment supported by `ssh`.  While `mosh` apparently has no verbose- or debug-options, you can tell it what `ssh` command to use when connecting and by adding a `-vvv` option can have `ssh` show what locale variables it *sends*.

For example, starting with

```
mosh -ssh='ssh -vvv' root@server
```

you might see

```
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = C  
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
```

for POSIX, and

```
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
```

which show that the server *confirms* variables which are used.  The remote `sshd` may ignore some of your environment depending on the setting of `AcceptEnv` in the configuration for `sshd` — or your user's `SendEnv` settings (in your `ssh` configuration).

Not all servers accept your locale variables via ssh.

Even with the configuration setup permissively, it's still possible (particularly since you are connecting to the **root** user) that someone has decided that the locale for that user should be POSIX.  For **root**, that makes some sense because you would get into less trouble by select/paste copying.

For example, some systems use `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh` to set the locale for interactive use.  That script differs from one system to another, and is the second place (after the ssh/sshd configurations) to consider when looking for an explanation why locale information is not passed to a remote system.  With Red Hat (CentOS) the script attempts to get information from system- and home-configuration, e.g.,

```
if [ -n "$LANG" ]; then
    saved_lang="$LANG"
    [ -f "$HOME/.i18n" ] && . "$HOME/.i18n" && sourced=1
    LANG="$saved_lang"
    unset saved_lang
else
    for langfile in /etc/locale.conf "$HOME/.i18n" ; do
        [ -f $langfile ] && . $langfile && sourced=1
    done
fi
```

SuSE is different, making assumptions about ssh and gdm *before* reading essentially the same files:

```
#
# lang.sh:      Set interactive language environment
#
# Used configuration files:
#
#     /etc/sysconfig/language
#     $HOME/.i18n
#

#
# Already done by the remote SSH side
#
test -z "$SSH_SENDS_LOCALE" || return

#
# Already done by the GDM
#
test -z "$GDM_LANG" || return
```

For your particular servers (version not specified), the script may differ from one release to another.  My Debian servers do not have that file - and rely upon the default system locale and gdm (which can differ) to set the interactive locale.  Your ssh connection could use a different value with the system locale than an interactive session using X (via gdm).  In that case, the system locale is the place to fix (see [Locale](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale) in the Debian wiki).

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the error message. However, the work-around as provided by @Petr did not work for me. I had to set the value of the `LC_ALL` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8`. Setting the `LANG` variable had no effect (as on my end it already had the correct value).

Also, I have a slight clarification:

You make this change in the *client environment*, i.e. where you run your `mosh` command.
You do *not* make this change in the *server environment*, i.e. where you are connecting to.

This was not intuitively obvious to me, when I first found this post.

Also, to elaborate a bit further: as stated, in my situation `LANG` was already set to `en_US.UTF-8`. However, various other variables where set differently:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
```

Presumably this leads to some confusion in the `mosh` application, whereas `ssh` doesn't fuss about it.

On my end, I'm connecting from a Pop!_OS 22.04 client environment to an Unbuntu 22.04 server environment

## Tip

Instead of changing the `LC_ALL` variable for the entire shell, you can also use the following alias:

```
alias mosh="export LC_ALL=\"en_US.UTF8\" && mosh"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116779) fixed my problem.

(This solution is for users having this problem with a Debian server, which is different from the specific question). My machine was a Debian LX container handled by Proxmox.

My machine had the `locales` package installed, but I needed to reconfigure it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

More specific information can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian).
It seems that some machine may have the `locale-gen` command (my machine did not).